# socat blocking on stdin

Tags: perl, bash, ssl, aix, socat

I have a bash script as follow on an AIX host, myscript.sh:

```
MODE="$1"
if [ "$MODE" == "start" ]; then
    socat -T100 -lf $LOGF -d -d -d -x TCP4-LISTEN:$LISTENINGPORT,bind=$LISTENINGADDR,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"$0 proxy" &
    PID=$!
    echo $PID > $PIDFILE
    echo "$0 $MODE started (pid=$PID)"

elif [ "$MODE" == "proxy" ]; then
    cat - > $TMPFILE
    # process $TMPFILE before the SSL connection.
    cat $TMPFILE | socat -T 100 -lf $LOGF -d - OPENSSL:$HOST
    rm -f $TMPFILE
```

Everything is fine when I run:

```
$ cat somefile | myscript.sh proxy | xxd
```

The problem raise when I connect to the socat listener with a test script:

```
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $fsize = -s $file;
my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new("127.0.0.1:$port")
    or die "Couldn't connect to remote host: $!";
$socket->autoflush(1);
binmode($socket);
open (FILE,$file);
binmode(FILE);
my $buffer ;
while(sysread(FILE, $buffer, $blocksize)) {
    print $socket $buffer ;
}
print "sent\n" ;
close (FILE) ;

my $answer = <$socket>;
if (defined($answer)) {
    print $answer; # never reached
print "...\n" ;
} else {
    die "connection reset by peer\n";
}
```

In myscript.sh, it blocks on the line:

```
cat - > $TMPFILE
```

In the test script, it blocks on the line:

```
my $answer = <$socket>;
```

At this point, the data has been received by the socat listener (checked with tcpdump).

However, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the test script before the socat timeout, the data goes through the pipe (i.e., the SSL server is eventually contacted).

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
Thanks for the tips about cat and EOF. For the time being, I have worked around the problem like so:

```
timeout 0.2 cat -u - > $TMPFILE 2>>/dev/null
# process $TMPFILE before the SSL connection.
cat $TMPFILE | socat -T 100 -lf $LOGF -d - OPENSSL:$HOST
```

It's ugly, and a waste 0.2 seconds, I hope to find a better solution.
But it does the job for now. The 2>>/dev/null part is because AIX complains about an invalid counter (related to the timeout command).

Comment: Is this script written in Perl? What are the left/right angle brackets for on `my $answer = <$socket>;`? Also, in the shell script, when is it terminating, as you're receiving data from the standard input (`cat -`)?

Comment: Yes, the test script is written in perl. The brackets mean "read whatever is readable", I would be happy to read even a single byte. And yes, when the test script is  killed, I get the whole thing from stdin.

Comment: Sorry, I must have not been clear; my second question is, when is it you have a termination on the standard input stream? If you don't receive an `EOF`, yes, `cat` will be stuck in its execution -- until you hit Ctrl+c, as you said.

Comment: So now you're really killing `cat - ` after some time of data receiving. Where is the data coming from, and couldn't the data sender itself send a termination to `cat -`? I mean, it's coming to the standard input, but is it you, typing contents to the file, or is it from the connection opened?

Comment: The data comes from 127.0.0.1. I don't really care what the sender is transmitting. If it is acceptable by the application protocol, it will hopefully go through, if not, too bad. I'll eventually need to troubleshot it. Still looking for a better solution...

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this is to check if you're able to add the "termination signal" to `cat -`. Actually, depending on where you're getting the information from, you might would be able to do the redirection in a single step, without using `cat - > $TMPFILE`.

Comment: How? I have no control at all on the application protocol. But I do need to grep something from it.

Comment: I've tried to make an example, please, check my answer; hope it works to you.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that there is no linefeed in the data you're trying to receive with `cat -` or `<STDIN>` . Both commands in their default behavior will return data once they have a linefeed or their buffers of the file-descriptor is full (4KB by default in Linux).

Comment: Indeed, there is no linefeed. It's binary protocol chat that need to be transmited over SSL

Comment: how much data do you send? Try `read` in perl, with a length of 1, in that case it should return very fast.

Comment: The amount of data varies between 0.5k and 3k. How would you invoque "perl read" from bash?